# How can I use namespaced helper functions in RazorEngine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razorengine

I'm using RazorEngine to build an email templating system and would like to maintain helper functions in separate cshtml files from my main templates. For instance, say I have a folder structure like this:

```
/Templates
    Support.cshtml
    Registration.cshtml
    Marketing.cshtml
/Helpers
    /Shared
        Common.cshtml
        Images.cshtml
    /Marketing
        Ads.cshtml
        Products.cshtml
```

What I'd like is for the templates to access the helpers like so:

```
<body>
    @Common.Header()
    <img src="@Images.Resize(@Model.ImageUrl)" />
</body>
```

But the reason I'd like them namespaced is because I'd like say the Ads team to be able to write and maintain helpers without worrying about naming conflicts with say the common helpers or any other team. They could confidently name a helper `Resize()` without worrying about `@Images.Resize` because their helper would be accessed as `@Ads.Resize` or `@Marketing.Ads.Resize()`.

This seems somewhat possible based on how helpers work in the native implementation of Razor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site) but our codebase is distributed and therefore doesn't have an App_Code folder, and also RazorEngine is different in a lot of ways so I haven't been able to get it to work.

Right now I've been getting my helpers into the templates by using string concatenation which also seems wrong, so is there a way I can make this work with RazorEngine?

Comment: You should look in to https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Razor pages are compiled in to simple classes and helpers becomes methods of these classes so you cannot put them under a namespace.

But, if you do not mind putting your cshtml files in a different class library project, then it is possible using an extension called "Razor Generator".

- Install "razor generator" from "extensions and updates".
- Restart Visual Studio and open your web project.
- Add a new class library project.
- Add a new cshtml (Ads.cshtml for example) file to recently created project.
- Write following text on first line of the file.

  @* Generator: MvcHelper GeneratePrettyNames : true *@
- place some business critical code in file

  @helper PlaceAd()
  {
      advertisement
  }
- In file properties, set "Custom Tool" to "RazorGenerator", and "Custom Tool Namespace" a namespace you would like
- reference this new dll from web application.
- Reference your new business critical helper from any view
- Profit

Comment: I am using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/86), not Razor. Will this strategy still work?

Comment: In theory, it should. You may need to use a Reference Resolver https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html. You may also need to add some using statements to viewstart.cshtml or view itself

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to move your code under Helper folder to App_Code:
1. Right clicking on your project (not solution) > Add > Add ASP.NET folder > App_Code
2. Create your template by using `@helper` syntax:

```
@helper MakeNote(string content) {
  <div class="note" 
       style="border: 1px solid black; width: 90%; padding: 5px; margin-left: 15px;">
    <p>
      <strong>Note</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; @content
    </p>
  </div>
}
```

3. Use the template that you created previously by declaring `@MyHelpers.MakeNote("My test note content.")`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Helpers Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is some opening paragraph text.</p>

    <!-- Insert the call to your note helper here. -->
    @MyHelpers.MakeNote("My test note content.")

    <p>This is some following text.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more info, you can visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site)